Ideal gas equation: Bernoulli's original derivation
I'm reading through some of Stephen Brush's books and i found Daniel Bernoulli's (1738, Hydrodynamica) original derivation of the Ideal gas law. In particular, this first part refers to the derivation of Boyle's law ($PV$ = constant, when keeping $T$ constant). I can't understand neither Bernoulli's nor Brush's explanation on parts of the derivation.
Consider a gas in a cylinder being compressed. The initial height of the cylinder es $h_0$ and the final height is $h_f$. The volume is reduced to a fraction $s$ ($V_f = s V_0$).
Bernoulli:

When the piston is lowered, it is subjected to a greater force by the fluid in two ways: first because the number of particles is now greater in proportion to the smaller space in which they are confined, and secondly because any given particle makes more frequent impacts.

First cause
Bernoulli's explanation:

In order correctly to calculate the increment due to the first cause, we shall consider the particles as being at rest, and put equal to $n_0$ the number of particles adjacent to the piston in its initial position; this number will become $n_0/(h_f/h_0)^{2/3}$ in the final position

Brush's:

If the motion of the piston reduces the volume to a fraction $s$, the surface area is reduced to a factor $s^{2/3}$; hence the pressure increases by a factor of $s^{-2/3}$

Second cause
Bernoulli's explanation:

Now as for the increment arising from the second cause, this is found by considering the motion of the particles; thus it is evident that the impacts occur more frequently in proportion to the reduction in the mutual distances of the particles; evidently the number of impacts will be inversely proportional to the mean distance between the surfaces of the particles.

Result
These two causes put together lead Bernoulli to the following result:
$$ P_f = \frac{P_0}{s} = \frac{P_0 V_0}{V_f} $$
My doubts
I'd be very grateful if someone could explain some of these to me. Thanks!

First cause: from what i understand from Bernoulli's explanation, i get a different result. Suppose the adjacent molecules to the piston are in a height $dz$, their number will be:

$$ n_0 = \frac{N}{V_0} A dz = \frac{N}{A h_0} A dz   
 = \frac{N}{h_0} dz$$
Where $A$ is the transverse area. In the final state this turns into:
$$ n_f = \frac{N}{V_f} A dz = \frac{N}{A h_f} A dz   
 = \frac{N}{h_f} dz$$
Thus i get
$$ n_f = \frac{h_0}{h_f} n_0 = \frac{V_0}{V_f} n_0 $$

First cause: i don't understand Brush's explanation and can't seem to link it to Bernoulli's.

Second cause: ¿how is the mean distance between molecules related to more frequent hits to the wall?


References
Bernoulli's original in:

Brush, The Kinetic Theory Of Gases: An Anthology Of Classic Papers With Historical Commentary, Part I, chapter 3.

Brush's explanation in:

Brush, Statistical Physics and the Atomic Theory of Matter, section 1.5.

Other:

In this post (https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/did-daniel-bernoulli-state-van-der-waals-equation) are mentions to some books that cover this topic. However, i found them of no help. Basically nothing new from Bernoulli's and Brush's explanations.


It seems like you are correct about the first cause and Brush might be making a huge mistake there. However, the form of the result really depends upon what it is you are keeping constant. Are you keeping temperature constant in this? Or are you forbidding heat transfer?

Probably Brush is right, at least his result is in line with Bernoulli's explanation, mine isn't. Temperature must be constant. The idea is to derive only Boyle's Law ($PV=$ constant)

I had to check both Brush's book and Feynman lectures, and found out that actually, both of us are correct and it is Brush and Bernoulli that are wrong. The actually correct classical atomic derivation of the ideal gas law has pressure $p=\frac13\frac NVm\left<v^2\right>$ i.e. it does not have anything to do with the mean distances between the particles. There is a theorem proving that collision between particles does not matter, and the pressure is the same as if each particle ignores colliding with others and just collides with the walls.

Thanks for the time! Perhaps you are right. I thought the "distance between particles" argument was a proxy to saying: this implies also more collisions with walls. But the theorem you mention makes a point. However, the result you are quoting is consistent with Bernoulli's result (see my edit: section Result) and i haven't seen any other sources stating this derivation is wrong.

The argument by Bernoulli is just fallacious. They knew the result has to be that $pV=$ const and worked backwards to get the $s^{2/3}$. It is not valid. The higher rate of collision with walls and the increase in number density are both true, but their contributions are made together and cannot be distinguished from each other.
